# OpenLayers: wrapDateLine not working, no error in JS console

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mapserver, map-files

Should be simple enough, not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
var layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("CustomerAirports", "http://192.168.2.164/cgi-  
bin/mapserv.exe", {map: '/data2/html/customer_airport.map', layers: ['CustomerAirports']}, 
{singleTile: true}, {wrapDateLine: true});
```

Based on what I've read, that should be working, should it not? No errors in console like I said.

Any input is appreciated.

Edit1: Just ended up switching the order of singleTile and wrapDateLine, seemed to do the trick.

Could also put singleTile and wrapDateLine within one pair of { } instead of separate ones.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using separate { } for singleTile and wrapDateLine, just do

```
{singleTile: true, wrapDateLine: true}
```

However, I'm not sure if singleTile is best when using wrapDateLine: things seem to get very sluggish.